# TypeError: (0, _react.useFocusEffect) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I want to try using `useFocusEffect` on a page in my React Native app. I am importing it like so:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useFocusEffect } from "react";
```

And I've added the function, with just a log statement to test, like so:

```js
useFocusEffect(() => {
  console.log('hi')
}, []);
```

As mentioned in the title, I get this error:

> TypeError: (0, _react.useFocusEffect) is not a function.

I read on other posts that there may be an issue with the import, however I don't think this is the case. I also saw some people saying that `useFocusEffect` is only for React-Navigation>4, I checked and my version is > 6 so I don't believe this to be the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`useFocusEffect`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) is exported from `@react-navigation/native`, not `react`. You will need to fix the imports.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
```